# Determining the asymptotic behavior of a sequence

Tags: co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, integer-sequences

I've encountered the following sequences

$$
a_k=2^{k+1}\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}a_{k-1-j}a_j,\;a_0=1
$$

$$
b_k=(k+1)\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}b_{k-1-j}b_j,\;b_0=1.
$$

I would like to have an estimate of the growth of these sequences as $k$ grows.

After looking here and there, I found the Catalan's numbers defined by
$$
C_k=\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}C_{k-1-j}C_j,\;C_0=1.
$$ 
They have an asymptotic growth of 
$$
C_k=2^{k+1}k^{-3/2}.
$$

I tried (unsuccesfully) to manipulate my original series to recover some form of the Catalan's numbers.

Any idea is very welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One type of Catalan's $q$-analogue is due to Carlitz ([see the paper for this and more](http://homepage.univie.ac.at/josef.hofbauer/85jct_catalan.pdf))
$$C_{n+1}(q)=\sum_{k=0}^nC_k(q)\,C_{n-k}(q)\,q^{(k+1)(n-k)}, \qquad C_0:=1.$$
[Blieberger and Kirschenhofer](http://institute.unileoben.ac.at/mathstat/personal/(2014)%20Generalized%20Catalan%20Sequences%20%5BEtc%5D.pdf) studied these Catalans, in equation (2), and the more related sequence $r_n$, in equation (5). They have found the asymptotics, on page 9, 
$$r_n\sim 2^{\frac{n^2+3n}2}\beta(1/2).$$
Now, your sequence is $a_n=2^nr_n$ and hence
$$a_n\sim 2^{\frac{n^2+5n}2}\beta(1/2);$$
where $\beta(1/2)\approx 0.7153374336\dots$.

J. Furlinger and J. Hofbauer, *$q$-Catalan Numbers*, Jour. of Comb. Theory, Series A, 40(2):248–264, 1985.

J. Blieberger, P. Kirschenhofer,
*Generalized Catalan Sequences Originating from the Analysis of Special Data Structures*, Bulletin of the Institute of Combinatorics and its Applications, 71 (2014), 103-116.

Answer (score 2):

For $b_k$:  Computing the first few terms and
searching into https://oeis.org returns [A218222](https://oeis.org/A218222)
and [A088716](https://oeis.org/A088716).

A088716 is very close to your sequence.

If $b_k$ is really A218222, from the comments:

$$ b_n \sim C 2^{n-1} (n-1)! (n-1)^2$$

Comment: Very similar to $a_k$ is https://oeis.org/A254744